# Cannot generate keystroke written to device kernel with input.h Linux

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-device-driver, keystroke

I am trying to generate keystrokes and write them to the kernel in Linux using the input library. I found an example form http://rico-studio.com/linux/read-and-write-to-a-keyboard-device/ and made a little test program. It should just print a bunch of t's but only does this when I strike a key (space for example) myself.

```
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <linux/uinput.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define EV_PRESSED 1
#define EV_RELEASED 0
#define EV_REPEAT 2



int main() {

    int fd = 0;

    /*In my case event3 handles the keyboard. This can be checked typing     
     *   cat /proc/bus/input/devices in the terminal
     */
    char *device = "/dev/input/event3";

    struct input_event event;

    memset(&event, 0, sizeof(event));

    gettimeofday(&event.time, NULL);
    if( (fd = open(device,  O_RDWR |  O_NONBLOCK )) < 0 )
    {
        printf("not opened "); // Read or Write to device
        return 0;
    }

    for(int i=0;i <500 ;i++)
    {
//      usleep(1000);
        event.type = EV_KEY;
        // Press the key down
        event.value = EV_PRESSED;
        event.code = KEY_T;

        write(fd, &event, sizeof(struct input_event));
//      usleep(1000);

        // Release the key
        event.value = EV_RELEASED;
        event.code = KEY_T;
        write(fd, &event, sizeof(struct input_event));
        usleep(100000);

    }
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe this key-stroke flushes the memory along with the generated keystrokes for t written to the devices memory? So I am wondering what I am missing to let it generate a keystroke and write it to the kernel all by itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `xxd /dev/input3` and break apart the output, you can see that the keyboard is also sending `EV_SYN`, `SYN_REPORT` events after each key change to mark the end of a grouped set of events. To do the same:

```
event.type = EV_SYN;
event.code = SYN_REPORT;
event.value = 0;
write(fd, &event, sizeof(struct input_event));
```